# Android - shouldn't calling finishActivity cause finish to be called?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have overridden the finish call in a sub-activity like so

```
   @Override
   public void finish() 
   {
      Log.e(this.toString(), "======== finish ========"); 
      if(!this.exiting)
      {
         Log.e(this.toString(), "======== set RESULT_OK ========"); 
         // Notify the caller Activity that the user successfully
         // edited or inserted the data set
         setResult(RESULT_OK);
      }
      else
      {   
         Log.e(this.toString(), "======== set RESULT_CANCELED ========"); 
         // Notify the caller Activity that the user has canceled the
         // activity without altering anything
         setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
      }

      super.finish();
   }
```

I am calling finishActivity on this sub-Activity from the Activity that started it for result.  But I am not seeing the finish being hit.  Instead it goes directly to onPause.

Comment: I don't see a single valid reason to override the finish() method in an activity.

Comment: I agree it's was an attempt at a total hack/bandaid.  Not something I intended to keep in long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) is the method that you call on Activity when you want to finish it (for example because you want it to return a result to calling Activity).

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what method gets called in the sub-activity when the activity that started it calls finishActivity.

Comment: Probably onPause, onStop and finally onDestroy.

Comment: You should call `setResult(..)` when user changes something, not inside `onPause` or `onStop`.

Comment: @Peter Knego - I think you're right about the order.  In my case my screen just displays status.  The user can then swipe left or right to view a different status screen.  I am trying to use the setResult as an indication to the parent Activity of RESULT_OK==show new screen, RESULT_CANCELED==Exit

Comment: That's ok, but why do you then kill subactivity from parent activity? Just set the result and call finish() inside the subactivity, after user is done with their choice.

Comment: @Peter Knego - I'm doing it the current way because when the user is done on one screen and swipes to go to the next I actually need to coordinate with a server and only move to the next screen after it approves.  The parent handles receiving that approval message.

Comment: Ok, understood. You could still call `setResult` after user action. Then kill the subactivity and you should get the result. Setting result inside `onPause()` or `onStop()` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The `finish`-Method is supposed to be called by you if you want to finish that activity manually, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is called when that activity is finished by other means.

Try using `onDestroy` instead.

Typically, only methods starting with "on" are meant to be hooked, like `onDestroy`. Other methods are usually just meant to be invoked.

Comment: I was trying this in order to call the setResult values.  Unfortunately it seems like onPause and then onDestroy is to late to set those.